# Xaml Code Block rendering in Visual Studio but is transparent when running built app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, material-design

i was trying to create a material design themed card in xaml using a basic but flexable layout. My clipping solution was from stackoverflow aswell. My Goal was to create a card that could hold any content without overflowing the rounded borders of the actual card.

i came up with the following

```
    <!-- Card Template Start -->
    <Grid Width="330" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,170,30,30" Panel.ZIndex="2">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2" >
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="8" ShadowDepth="2.5" Direction="270" Color="Black" Opacity=".23"/>
            </Border.Effect>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=ClipMask}" Stretch="None" />
                </Grid.OpacityMask>
                <Border x:Name="ClipMask" Background="White" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Beige" />
                <!-- Content + Controls here pl0x -->
                <Grid>
                    <!-- Top Header / Button / Whatever you want -->
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Button Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="14">BoatsBoatsBoats!</Button>
                    </Grid>

                    <!-- Floating Button -->
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionDarkButton}" Panel.ZIndex="10" Margin="0,30,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <Viewbox Width="24" Height="24">
                            <Canvas Width="24" Height="24">
                                <Path Data="M12,20A7,7 0 0,1 5,13A7,7 0 0,1 12,6A7,7 0 0,1 19,13A7,7 0 0,1 12,20M12,4A9,9 0 0,0 3,13A9,9 0 0,0 12,22A9,9 0 0,0 21,13A9,9 0 0,0 12,4M12.5,8H11V14L15.75,16.85L16.5,15.62L12.5,13.25V8M7.88,3.39L6.6,1.86L2,5.71L3.29,7.24L7.88,3.39M22,5.72L17.4,1.86L16.11,3.39L20.71,7.25L22,5.72Z" Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}" />
                            </Canvas>
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Button>

                    <!-- Content -->
                    <Grid Margin="0,50,0,50">

                    </Grid>

                    <!-- Bottom Footer / Button / Whatever you want -->
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                        <Button Height="50" Width="110" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Prev</Button>
                        <Button Height="50" Width="110" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}">Spectate</Button>
                        <Button Height="50" Width="110" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">Next</Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Now when i'm in Visual Studio everything seems to render without any issues.
After building the app and using it the card doesnt render at all.

the code above is part of an open source project i'm contributing to and i'm still learning xaml and c#
https://github.com/LegendaryClient/LegendaryClient/commit/3655664d072f79693de75b005604811df1d94216

anyone an idea?
mention: my xaml is def more better than my c#, thats why i tried a xaml only solution here.

Comment: It could be many things... Visibility, ZIndexes, Clipping...  I suggest you use a tool like Snoop to check the visual tree and see what's being rendered. This should help figuring out the culprit.

Comment: Transparent = missing background brush usually.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem but I couldn't. It renders perfectly fine at runtime when I remove the `StaticResource` references to `MaterialDesignFloatingActionDarkButton` and `MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton`. Could you also post these styles? Unfortunately I couldn't find it in the repo you specified.

Comment: its from the nuget package Material Design Themes and Material Design Colors.

Comment: FYI, the clipping is now fixed in Material Design In XAML Toolkit using the Card control.